Looking for a 4-monitor stand in Australia
I can google for 4-monitor stands, but I need to by it in Australia as I am moving there.  I haven't a clue where to buy these things.
Could someone recommend a 4-monitor stand for monitors such as HP 233, in Australia.

Not price sensitive
Should be robust (not flimsy or shaky)
Needs to bolt firmly to a timber desk (I can drill holes etc)
Monitors are about 310mm X 520mm


I ended up buying this one after looking at various suppliers and brands.  The feedback suggested that they were strong.  And they have an alternative mounting method as well.

Blurb from site


Compatibility: The monitor mount fits most flat panel monitor up to 27 inch and supports weight up to 22lbs per arm. Mount plates detachable and height adjustable adapt to mounting holes 75x75mm and 100x100mm.
Multiple Options: The two-stage locking system adapt to 4” C-clamp and 3” Grommet Base.
Multiple Adjustment: The high-grade arms extend and retract, +/-90° tilt and swivel to change reading angles, and 360° rotate from landscape to portrait mode.
Double Benefits: Monitor arm is easily adjustable on a 31.5” height pole. Double efficiency and productivity by opening up desk space allow working in a more comfortable, ergonomically correct position to reduce neck and eye strain.
Package Includes: WALI Quad Monitor Mount (Black) x 1, Mounting Hardware Kit, User Manual, experienced and friendly US based customer support available to assist 7 days a week.


I am not associated with Amazon or supplier

Most are either too small or too flimsy.
You are best to build your own by Ordering two STUBBERGET from Ikea and joining them. This gives you better flexibility than most big brand brackets.

While it may work well for 2 monitors. I can't see how I could use 2 of these to stack 4 monitors in a 2X2 format.  :-)
